# compiling typescript and keep directory structure correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a build and a src dir. And in my src dir with my public folder where all my css's, assets and html's and the server folder with all server files. And now for an example in my server.ts I use a view in `public/html`. And if I transpiling my code in the build folder only the .ts files are and then the server.js tries to find the view in `cmpl/public/html`...

What is now a good way to transpiling the full src folder to build? Can Gulp this? Or TSC directly?

Greetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copy your html files to `cmpl` directory:

```
gulp.task('copyHtml', function () {
  return gulp
    .src('public/html/**/*.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('cmpl'));
});
```